# Python chromedriver can't launch browser

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with selenium webdriver version 2.49.2 and Python2.7.7.  Windows.  I have chromedriver.exe in 'C:/Python27' and 'C:/Python27/Scripts', and both of these added to the Path variable.  My code fails at 
`browser=webdriver.Chrome()`
I also tried

`browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe")` but had the same result.

There's a black window like the command line window for a split second, but the browser window doesn't appear.

The error message is blank so it's difficult to troubleshoot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\python\script.py", line 88, in <module>
    scrape(db_params)
  File "C:\path\to\python\script.py", line 39, in scrape
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 188, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message:
```

Can anyone suggest anything I'm missing please?

Comment: But what is the error message on the stacktrace?

Comment: @alecxe, that's the thing, it was blank!  Or more specifically, it was a new line char '\n'

Comment: Okay, nice, please try with selenium 2.48: `pip install selenium==2.48`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with loading the chromedriver from the path (or environment variables).

What does seem to work is to pass the full path to chromedriver.exe in the webdriver.Chrome constructor like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Hi Harold.  I tried this and got the same result.  I'll edit that into the question.  Apologies - I've lost track of the various things I tried reading similar answers!

Comment: @Meelah hmm - this works for me although I've got a Mac

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and even if I used :

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe")
```

the error still showed up.

I fixed it by using the latest version of chromedriver.

My current chrome version is v54, so I used chromedriver v2.25 which the release notes stated it supports Chrome v53-55.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/

Answer (score 0):

for windows

Run in command prompt to check the chrome version

reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version

Note the version and download the relevent chrome driver 
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Replace the file and then try to run the python code

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error. I tried with various version of chromedriver. Finally latest version(ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140) worked.